# Amazon QuickSight - Can we call "GenerateEmbedUrlForAnonymousUser" API via internet?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I couldn't find the URL of this API. I want to get the url of embed dashboard for anonymous users. Please help me. I tried many things, but didn't work. Sometimes I found the response which shows "Missing Authentication Token". I guess I mistake the URL. Please help me.